# Inline throw() method in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, throw

I am trying to define a really simple exception class. Because it is so simple I want to keep it in the .h file only, but the compiler doesn't like `throw()`. The code:

```
#include <exception>
#include <string>

class PricingException : public virtual std::exception
{
private:
    std::string msg;
public:
        PricingException(std::string message) : msg(message) {}
        const char* what() const throw() { return msg.c_str(); }
        ~PricingException() throw() {}
};
```

GCC gives the following errors:

```
/home/ga/dev/CppGroup/MonteCarlo/PricingException.h:13: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
/home/ga/dev/CppGroup/MonteCarlo/PricingException.h:14: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
```

for lines with `throw()`. Any idea how to fix it?

**EDIT**

I tried to remove the bodies of the problematic methods, i.e.

```
virtual ~PricingException() throw();// {}
```

And now I get even more weird error message:

```
/home/ga/dev/CppGroup/MonteCarlo/PricingException.h:14: error: looser throw specifier for ‘virtual PricingException::~PricingException()’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/exception:65: error:   overriding ‘virtual std::exception::~exception() throw ()’
```

It just ignored my throw specifier!

Comment: compiles fine here with gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)

Comment: I am running `gcc (Debian 4.5.2-4) 4.5.2`

Comment: `#include <exception>` ? `#include <string>` ?

Comment: @Charles, yes, I have both - updated the question.

Comment: Works for me. command line was simply `g++ -o foo.o -c foo.cc` and `gcc --version` gives `gcc (Gentoo 4.4.5 p1.2, pie-0.4.5) 4.4.5`.

Comment: Works for me with `gcc-4.5.2` (which would be the same version as yours, except mine is from Gentoo 4.5.2 p1.1). This was my example code: https://ideone.com/KUBmN

Comment: Your code compiles fine with gcc 3.4, 4.2 and gcc 4.4. Do you have some exception featur4es turned off? Are you using an older version?

Comment: Seems no problem in the code. But why you are using virtual inheritance here?

Comment: @Serge: it's recommended by Stroustrup.

Comment: @Grzenio: have you tried using `noexcept` instead of `throw()` (without parenthesis thus) ? It's equivalent, but the different wording could influence the compiler.

Comment: Possibly a different header file is using the preprocessor to redefine `throw` (a thoroughly evil practise, but not unheard of). You could use `g++ -E` to see the preprocessed source, and check whether the `throw()` specifications are still intact when they reach the compiler.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: "it's recommended by Stroustrup" For what kind of task? Stroustrup recommends lots of different features for lots of different tasks. Can you post reference (book,chapter,page) and quote recommendation text you mean in your statement. Does he recommend producing exception classes from std::exception using virtual inheritance?

Comment: @Serge: somewhere in the "C++ Language 3rd edition" is as precise as I can get, I haven't read it for a while. There was not any clause as far as I can remember, which means it was an unconditional recommendation. The idea was probably that this is the most flexible way, and the performance loss on exception is not worth the loss of flexibility (since it's exceptional, right ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it finally! @Mike Seymour was right in his comment - it turns out that in a file nr3.h (part of [Numerical Recepies](http://www.nr.com/) code) there is a macro `throw(message)` defined.

What I don't understand is why it impacts compilation of files that don't include this .h file...

Anyway, I think Visual Studio had a different compilation order or something, so it was pure luck that it compiled there and not under gcc.

Answer (score 4):

Try the C++0x syntax instead, g++ 4.5 may be recent enough to support it:

```
const char* what() const noexcept { return msg.c_str(); }
```

However, this shouldn't matter (wording from draft 3242, section `[except.spec]`:

> Two *exception-specifications* are *compatible* if:
>
> - both are non-throwing (see below), regardless of their form,
> - both have the form `noexcept(`*constant-expression*`)` and the *constant-expressions* are equivalent,
> - one *exception-specification* is a *noexcept-specification* allowing all exceptions and the other is of the form `throw(`*type-id-list*`)`, or
> - both are *dynamic-exception-specifications* that have the same set of adjusted types.

.

> If a virtual function has an *exception-specification*, all declarations, including the definition, of any function that overrides that virtual function in any derived class shall only allow exceptions that are allowed by the *exception-specification* of the base class virtual function.

.

> A function with no *exception-specification* or with an *exception-specification* of the form `noexcept(`*constant-expression*`)` where the *constant-expression* yields false allows all exceptions. An *exception-specification* is
>   *non-throwing* if it is of the form `throw()`, `noexcept`, or `noexcept(`*constant-expression*`)` where the *constant-expression* yields `true`. A function with a non-throwing *exception-specification* does not allow any exceptions.

So try a newer build of g++, where these changes may be more completely implemented.

Comment: Just confirmed that it worked fine with clang ToT and g++ 4.5.2 (mingw version).

Answer (score 3):

The closest I have found in the C++0x is:

**15.4 Exception specifications [except.spec]**

> 2  An exception-specification shall appear only on a function declarator for a function type, pointer to function type, reference to function type, or pointer to member function type that is the top-level type of a declaration or definition, or on such a type appearing as a parameter or return type in a function declarator.

It looks to me like it could disallow the use of exception specifications on definitions.

Comment: Every definition is a declaration, isn't it?

Comment: Even the quoted paragraph says "or definition".

Comment: @Charles: I would associate it with what come before: "or pointer to member function type that is the top-level type of a declaration or definition" because it is followed by a comma and another member of the alternative.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I would say so, thus the *could disallow* as I am unsure of how to interpret this piece. I'd be happy with anyone with more experience chipping in, my answer was meant to bring some water to the mill, not to end the discussion :)

Comment: @Matthieu: Not only that, but the definition is *required* to carry an *exception-specification* matching the declaration.  Read para 4 of that same section.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: yes, I saw this one, which is why I am wondering why it happens. I'm beginning to suspect a buggy or non up-to-date implementation as the wordings have changed in the evolution of the draft I think.

Comment: @Matthieu: I agree, it's probably a bug/partially finished implementation in that particular version.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce this in several versions of g++. The most likely problem is that a previously included header file has a problem that's finally causing the compiler trouble when it sees the `throw` but not before.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `throw` with out the ()? in this example (i know its in the .cpp file) but you see that the throws all do not have a parenthesis

http://www.glenmccl.com/eh_cmp.htm

Comment: Where? At the bottom of the page they say `one with:

        throw()

is not allowed to throw exceptions at all.`

Comment: These are exception specifications, not throw expressions, and need the parentheses.